# Fatal Python Error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec ofthe filesystem encoding. Issue With Using <Python.h> in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, python-3.x, fatal-error, modulenotfounderror

I am attempting to execute a python file during my Qt Creator project runtime (which is in c++). In order to do this I downloaded python311 and added these lines to my .pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include"

LIBS += -L"C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs" -l"python311"
```

Then, in my application (specifically in my mainwindow.cpp file), I run the following code in order to execute the python file:

```
FILE* fp;
const char* file = "C:/(absolute path)/(filename).py";
Py_Initialize();
fp = fopen(file, "r");
PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, file);
Py_Finalize();
```

However, upon running the program, the program crashes when this is invoked. Using debugging mode, the Application Output section contains the following error message:

```
mincore\com\oleaut32\dispatch\ups.cpp(2126)\OLEAUT32.dll!00007FFF014C470C: (caller: 00007FFF014C49FA) ReturnHr(1) tid(6750) 8002801D Library not registered.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = 'C
:\Qt\Tools\m
ingw
1120
_64\bi
n\..
\opt'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'p
ytho
n'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  safe_path = 0
  import site = 1
  is in build tree = 0
  stdlib dir = 'C
:\Qt\
Tools\mingw
1120_64
\opt\Li
b'
  sys._base_executable = 'C:\\Users\\(name)\\(one drive)\\Documents\\(project name)_Qt_6_5_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\debug\\(project name).exe'
  sys.base_prefix = 
'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\bin\\..\\opt'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = 'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\bin\\..\\opt'
  sys.platlibdir = 'DLLs'
  sys.executable = 'C:\\Users\\(name)\\(one drive)\\Documents\\(project name)_Qt_6_5_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\debug\\(project name).exe'
  sys.prefix = 'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\bin\\..\\opt'
  sys.exec_prefix = 'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\bin\\..\\opt'
  sys.path = [
    'C:\\Users\\(name)\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\python311.zip',
    'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\opt\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Qt\\Tools\\mingw1120_64\\opt\\Lib',
    'C:\\Users\\(name)\\(one drive)\\Documents\\(project name)_Qt_6_5_1_MinGW_64_bit-Debug\\debug',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00006750 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
Fatal Python error: 
failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
```

Could anybody help me understand how to solve this issue? I am inexperienced with python and therefore do not understand the error message. I see one potential issue in the different python versions being referenced (one I downloaded myself: 311, and the other autoinstalled with the Qt mingw64 installer), but other than that I don't understand what is going wrong.

I have tried adjusting the PYTHONPATH and PYTHONHOME variable from both the command line and the advanced settings gui, but these had seemingly no effect on the outcome of the program (although it is possible I did not change them correctly).

Comment: The error is because python couldn't find its stdlib. Setting PYTHONHOME to `C:\Users\(name)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Ryan's answer above, in the absence of the environmental variable PYTHONHOME, Python uses the parent directory of the executable as the Python environment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35669387)